# Getting CORS policy error when trying to authorize a user in keycloak using REST api

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm trying to authorize a user in Keycloak using REST api.
API call is successful when I am calling the api from POSTMAN, but when trying from angular app I'm getting below error -

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/realmname/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Headers and body for the request is below -

[image: Headers & Body]

Comment: What authentication flow are you using ? I suspect your trying to use Direct Grant, which is not supposed to be done from a browser. You should use implicit or standard flow where you wouldn't have CORS issues.

Comment: @ldclrcq ,  I have tried with implicit flow, and in my keycloak server,I have enabled implicit flow and auth flow overrides as direct grant.